# Adding Pairwise Products

Tags: python

I'm taking a python class where we are asked the following question:

> Write a Python function that returns the sum of the pairwise products of listA and listB. You should assume that listA and listB have the same length and are two lists of integer numbers. For example, if listA = [1, 2, 3] and listB = [4, 5, 6], the dot product is 1*4 + 2*5 + 3*6, meaning your function should return: 32

I understand what I'm being asked for here, my issue is I don't know how to iterate through one list and fetch the value of the other one without loosing my index location.

Edit, I was looking at this the hard way and didn't even realize that because the lists are the same length the index would be the same for both, as miltuple people pointed out I can use zip and came up with:

```
def dotProduct(listA, listB):
    print(sum(a*b for (a,b) in zip(listA, listB)))
```

when I execute it i'm not sure why I'm receiving a value of "None" below the sum?

```
a = dotProduct([-26, -80, -93, -41, 45], [17, -69, -15, 8, -93])
print a
1960
None
>>>
```

Last EDIT: I figured out the NONE issue, instead of printing inside the function, I changed it to return the result.

Comment: the index will be the same for both, since they are the same length

Comment: You can iterate through the indices instead of the elements of one list.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same index as lengths are the same:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(0, len(listA)):
    sum += listA[i] * listB[i]
print(sum)
```

or you can use generator expressions:

```
print(sum(a*b for (a,b) in zip(listA, listB)))
```

Answer (score 1):

A functional method:

```
from itertools import starmap
from operator import mul

listA = [1, 2, 3]
listB = [4, 5, 6]

print(sum(starmap(mul, zip(listA, listB))))
```